# Waiting for user input with jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to wait to take the user's input (clicking a button) before continuing with the program. A simplified version of the code is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var answer = $(".question").on("click", "button", takeAnswer);
    alert(answer);
});
//Code to set the next question once the user has answered the previous question

function takeAnswer(){
    var answer = ($(".question button").data("answer"));
    alert(answer);
    return answer;
}
```

The `HTML` body simply contains this:

```
<p class="question"><button data-answer="1">Push me</button></p>
```

On loading, the HTML alerts `[object Object]`. once you click the button, the page alerts `1` as it is supposed to. I think the problem is that the `return` line is executing without awaiting the user's click. My research suggests that I need to use a callback function (there are several discussions on waiting for user input), but I'm confused because I thought that putting the `takeAnswer` code in a separate function would keep the subsequent code from executing.

For further context, my goal is to ask a series of choose-your-own-adventure style questions, changing later questions based on earlier user input. I intend to use jQuery to remove the previous question and place the new question, according to logic within the JavaScript file. **Edit 1:** I should also mention that I am pretty new to this and am trying to teach myself (if that's not already obvious).

**Edit 3:** Here is the full context in JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/T7VhC/ The problem is the "undefined" error arising from line 144 of the JS.

**Edit 2:**

Eventually I want to add other buttons and capture which button was clicked. Here is a simplified example of another (dysfunctional because, I think, there is no callback) attempt to implement what I'm doing:

```
function takeAnswer(){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".question").on("click", "button", function(){
      return $(this).data("answer");
    });
  });
}

alert(takeAnswer());
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <p class="question"><button data-answer="1">Push me</button></p>
  <p class="question"><button data-answer="2">Or push me</button></p>
</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting here: `var answer = $(".question").on("click", "button", takeAnswer);` because then `answer` equal `$(".question")`

Comment: Dou you want 1 as output ,on 1) Document Load and on 2) Button click?

Comment: I guess, you should use: `$(takeAnswer)` which will call function on DOM ready

Comment: @PratikJoshi, I want the output corresponding to the button's `data` tag on button click. I have the multiple `alert`s to help me see / help illustrate when the various statements are executing.

Answer (score 0):

For complete code, you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".question").on("click", "button", takeAnswer);
});
//Code to set the next question once the user has answered the previous question

$(takeAnswer);

function takeAnswer(){
  var answer = $(".question button").data("answer");
  alert(answer);
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it alerts "1" every time. If I have a second button with data "2" this doesn't capture that data, right?

Comment: @Ethan826 again you aren't explaining what you are expecting, so i'm still confused Now if you want more accurate help, provide a jsfiddle which reproduces your issue, could be easier to understand it

Comment: apologies. I have added a JSFiddle link to the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var answer = $(".question").on("click", "button", takeAnswer);
  takeAnswer();
});
//Code to set the next question once the user has answered the previous question

function takeAnswer(){
  var answer = ($(".question button").data("answer"));
  alert(answer);
  return answer;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think this is still problematic because it always alerts `1`. I have edited my question to  reflect the fact that I want to return the `data` value from one among several buttons.